# Panel to_excel with >256 columns

Tags: python, excel, pandas, panel, dataframe

I have pandas Panel with shape 5 * 500 * 5000. I want to save it to Excel file using Panel.to_excel.

When I try to save to xls file it throws ValueError: column index (256) not an int in range(256). As I understand it doesn't support more than 256 columns.

xlsb format is not supported by this function.
I can save to xlsx or xlsm but it takes huge time and computer resources.

Alternatively I can manually split panel into several dataframes and save it into several csv files but I want to have one file for this data. Can I do that?

Comment: I would personally not try to put that much data through Excel in any circumstance. If you are trying to save it for later reuse in Python, try HDF5.

Comment: is it possible to just use csv?  no limits there.

Comment: AZhao, I implemented csv solution at the moment. Data is saved into 5 csv files (the lowest dimension size). But I wondered if it is possible to save into one file.

Comment: The easiest non-Excel solution is to "pickle" the panel/dataframe with Panel.to_pickle(path). You may then read it with pandas.read_pickle(path)